# Custom user page for rails using devise - Using Rails 4 and Ruby - 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am currently using devise for authentication which generates user.rb and controller for user, Welcome page(root page after authentication) which is main page of application where I need to show the total number of user created account in application, number of subject opted by current user and other details of current user. I am unable to route to user page when I am using the same user.rb and user_controller.rb.

routes.rb

```
  root "welcome_pages#home"
  devise_for :users
  resources :subjects
  resources :books
```

application.html.erb

```
    <%= link_to "Home",  root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Books",   books_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Subjects", subjects_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
```

What am I missing ? I am getting the following errors

```
No route matches [GET] "/users_path"
```

Let me know if I need to provide more informations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta add user resource separately, something like:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
  .....
end
```

users controller

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

1. preferred version since _user.html.erb will be reusable

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= render @users %> #this iterates thru all users and invokes _user partial
```

views/users/_user.html.erb

```
<%= user.name %> #in this case you don't need @ since you used this rails shortcut @user.each do |user|.
```

2. version

views views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each |user| do %>
  <%= user.name %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: If routes error can be removed Is it possible to get all user in index.html.erb ? if so how ?